# pair-wise Cross-correlation of different time-series in r

Tags: r, time-series, lag, cross-correlation

I'm new to R and want to find the time lag between every two time time-series in a list. I have 52 different time series and I want create a matrix like out in which time lag between every two time-series is indicated.

Comment: Welcome to S.O. Please read: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Try posting some example data (or reusing example data from an R package dealing with time series).

Comment: `ccf` function is what you need. However, you should give a some example data as suggested above.